# I cannot get the text to show on this quotes slider

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

The quotes slider doesn't seem to be loading the text, the buttons and dots are there however the actual quotes in the center are not showing within them there is just a bundle of dots and buttons carefully placed in the center of the screen where the quotes should be. How do I make it so that the quotes show up within the slider buttons
HTML

```
            <div class="testimonials">
        <div class="slideshow-container">
            <div class="mySlides">
                <q>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores, vel?</q>
                <p class="author">Name Name</p>
            </div>
            <div class="mySlides">
                <q>Quibusdam adipisci ab explicabo. Porro exercitationem delectus nam unde corporis.</q>
                <p class="author">Name Name</p>
            </div>
            <div class="mySlides">
                <q>Beatae saepe ab sed, nihil perferendis et, pariatur dolores! Vel.</q>
                <p class="author">Name Name</p>
            </div>
            <a class="prev" onclick='plusSlides(-1)'>&#10094;</a>
            <a class="next" onclick='plusSlides(1)'>&#10095;</a>
        </div>
        <div class="dot-container">
            <span class="dot" onclick='currentSlide(1)'></span>
            <span class="dot" onclick='currentSlide(2)'></span>
            <span class="dot" onclick='currentSlide(3)'></span>
        </div>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
    .testimonials {
        height: 800px;
    }

    .slideshow-container {
        position: relative;
        background: #f1f1f1;
    }

    .mySlides {
        display: none;
        padding: 80px;
        text-align: center;
     }

    .prev, .next {
        cursor: pointer;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        width: auto;
        margin-top: -30px;
        padding:16px;
         color: #888;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 20px;
        border-radius: 0 3px 30px 0;
        user-select: none;
    }

    .next {
        position: absolte;
        right: 0;
        border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
     }

     .prev:hover, .next:hover {
          background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
          color:white;
     }

      .dot-container {
           text-align: center;
          padding: 20px;
         background: #ddd;
    }

    .dot {
         cursor: pointer;
         height: 15px;
         width: 15px;
         margin: 0 2px;
         background: #bbb;
         border-radius: 50%;
         display: inline-block;
         transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
     }

.active, .dot:hover {
    background: #717171;
}

q {
    color: #1c1c1c;
    font-style: italic;
}

.authour {
    color: aqua;
}
```

Comment: All of your `.mySlides`'s are set to `display:none`, I assume there's some JS that should be controlling this? With them set to `block`, it looks fine to me.

Comment: Thanks just noticed this.